# Bootstrap is not working while using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a table which column & row will be created from JSON using jquery. The problem is,table is being created but there is no border & bootstrap is working for  in    but its not working for  in .I am not sure as i am new is JQuery, what is the problem??.I want a border  and bootstrap to be worked for whole table.

My code is:

```
  <body>
  <table id="tableId" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
         <tr id="header">

          </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr id="nonHeader">

         </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

```
<script>
var tableData=[
    {
        firstHeader: "Id",
        secondHeader: "First Name",
        thirdHeader: "Last Name",
        fourthHeader: "Father's Name",
        fifthHeader:"Value"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: "Peter",
        lastName: "Jhons",
        fatherName: "fons",
        value:1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: "David",
        lastName: "Bowie",
        fatherName: "kons",
        value:2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        firstName: "kevin",
        lastName: "Bowie",
        fatherName: "mons",
        value:3
    }
]
function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(i==0){
            drawHeader(data[i])
        }

        else{
            drawRow(data[i]);
        }


    }
}

function drawHeader(rowData){
   var row = $("<tr/>")
    $("#nonHeader").append(row);
    for (var key in rowData) {
        if (rowData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            row.append($("<th>" + rowData[key] + "</th>"));

        }
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr/>")
    $("#nonHeader").append(row);

    for (var key in rowData) {
        if (rowData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            console.log(rowData[key]);
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData[key] + "</td>"));
            console.log(key + " -> " + rowData[key]);
        }
    }
}
drawTable(tableData);

</script>
```

Comment: Have you included bootstrap sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below

1.add id="nonHeader" to tbody instead of tr

```
<tbody id="nonHeader">

</tbody>
```

2. add bootstrap class table-border

HTML:

```
<body>
  <table id="tableId" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
         <tr id="header">

          </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="nonHeader">

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS:

```
var tableData=[
    {
        firstHeader: "Id",
        secondHeader: "First Name",
        thirdHeader: "Last Name",
        fourthHeader: "Father's Name",
        fifthHeader:"Value"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: "Peter",
        lastName: "Jhons",
        fatherName: "fons",
        value:1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: "David",
        lastName: "Bowie",
        fatherName: "kons",
        value:2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        firstName: "kevin",
        lastName: "Bowie",
        fatherName: "mons",
        value:3
    }
]
function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(i==0){
            drawHeader(data[i])
        }

        else{
            drawRow(data[i]);
        }


    }
}

function drawHeader(rowData){
    console.log("Data rowwwww")
    console.log(rowData);




    for (var key in rowData) {
        var row = $("<th/>")
        $("#header").append(row);

        if (rowData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            row.append($("<th>" + rowData[key] + "</th>"));
            console.log(key + " -> " + rowData[key]);
        }
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {

    var row = $("<tr/>")
    $("#nonHeader").append(row);

    for (var key in rowData) {





        if (rowData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            console.log(rowData[key]);
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData[key] + "</td>"));
            console.log(key + " -> " + rowData[key]);
        }
    }


}
drawTable(tableData);
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pbmRJa